# Latency increase with the time on display + record pipeline

Tags: c++, gstreamer

Below is my pipeline to display and record my stream coming from an udp source. The problem is that a latency increase (start at no latency) with the time on my stream and my record. However, if I just display my stream, there is no latency.

Can someone have an of where the problem can come ?

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc name=source ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! tee name = t ! queue ! avenc_mpeg4 bitrate=10000000 ! matroskamux name=matrox !filesink name=myFile t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! d3dvideosink name=mysink sync=false", &error);
```

Thanks,

EDIT :

All my save and display code :

```
    void MainWindow::SaveVideo()
    {
            std::string strPathVideo = m_VideoPath + CreateFileName("mkv");
            GError* error = NULL;
            GstElement* source;
            GstElement* filesink;
            GstElement* matrox;
            GstElement* clocktime;
            //GstElement* compression;
            GstElement* textoverlay;
            GstElement* sink;
            GstPad* padsink;
            GstCaps* caps = gst_caps_new_simple("application/x-rtp",
                "media", G_TYPE_STRING, "video",
                "payload", G_TYPE_INT, 96,
                "encoding-name", G_TYPE_STRING, "H264",
                NULL);
    
(*ptrstats).pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc name=source ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! textoverlay halignment=center valignment=top name=text ! tee name = t ! queue ! avenc_mpeg4 bitrate=10000000 ! matroskamux name=matrox !filesink name=myFile t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! d3dvideosink name=mysink sync=false", &error);
                textoverlay = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "text");
                g_object_set(G_OBJECT(textoverlay), "text", m_text.ToStdString(), NULL);
            }
    
            if (!(*ptrstats).pipeline) {
                 outfile << "Save : ", error->message ,"\n";
                 exit(1);
            }
            sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "mysink");
    
            filesink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "myFile");
            g_object_set(filesink, "location", strPathVideo.c_str(), NULL);
    
            //compression = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "compression");
            //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(compression), "bitrate", m_intcompression, NULL);
    
            matrox = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "matrox");
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(matrox), "offset-to-zero", true, NULL);
    
            source = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "source");
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "caps", caps, NULL);
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "port", m_port, NULL);
    
            textoverlay = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "text");
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(textoverlay), "text", m_text.ToStdString(), NULL);
    
            padsink = gst_element_get_static_pad(sink, "sink");
            gst_pad_add_probe(padsink, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, (GstPadProbeCallback)buffer_sink, ptrstats, NULL);
            gst_object_unref(padsink);
    
            (*ptrstats).bus = gst_element_get_bus(GST_ELEMENT((*ptrstats).pipeline));
    
        #ifdef __WXGTK__
            GstElement* sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "mysink");
            gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink), m_xid);
        #elif defined __WXMSW__
    
            WXWidget hwnd = (*ptrstats).m_renderWindow->GetHandle();
            gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink),
                reinterpret_cast<guintptr>(hwnd));
        #endif
    
            PlayHelper();
        
    }
    
    void MainWindow::PlayHelper()
    {
        GstStateChangeReturn ret =
            gst_element_set_state((*ptrstats).pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    
        if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
        {
            outfile << "Playhelper : Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n";
            wxLogWarning("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.");
            gst_object_unref((*ptrstats).pipeline);
            (*ptrstats).pipeline = NULL;
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes sorry, edit done